# How to deploy PHP Lumen API Code in Azure Web App

Tags: php, laravel, api, azure-web-app-service, lumen

I want to deploy lumen code in Azure Web App Service. I am following [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-php?pivots=platform-linux) to create PHP Web App in Azure App Service. I am able to create and launch simple `Hello World` Application as mentioned here.

Now, I want to deploy actual Lumen code in Azure App. I cloned lumen application using `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/lumen myfolder`
command and trying to serve the application using `php -S localhost:8000 -t public` (used my azure server name instead `localhost:8000`) command. But It is not working.

How to deploy and How to serve this Application in server?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to set the default page? Please show the details of what you get.

After you deploy the app, it should works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Move your lumen application outside public_html.**
**Move your index.php file in subdomain.**
**Edit index.php set route to your subdomain**

Command for different host:

```
php -s localhost:8000 -t public/
```

used your azure server name instead of localhost:8000

Sometimes Php artisan serve not work properly so you can use

```
http://localhost/here_project_name/public/
```

Please refer: https://www.tutsmake.com/laravel-command-php-artisan-serve-not-working-properly/

For Deploy Laravel Lumen on Azure Web App

Please refer:https://medium.com/swlh/deploy-laravel-5-8-on-azure-web-app-2019-3514eb2fd1af